# "No such file or directory" when Executing Test RPC

Tags: testnets, testrpc, ubuntu

I installed testrpc using the following:

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

NPM -v: 5.3.0

NodeJS -v: v8.5.0

Now, whenever I try to initialize a random testnet by running the command:

```
$ testrpc
```

I get an error saying:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘node\r’: No such file or directory
```

I'm really not sure what to do and could not find any other examples of this question on the web. If it matters, I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.